How to revert rpm-ostree reset?
For debugging reasons, I executed rpm-ostree reset and booted into the new deployment. But how do I revert that?
I can obviously boot into the previous old deployment. However, if I upgrade or so, I still do end up in the new deployment, with all my layered packages etc. being removed.
I do not want that, this was just a test after all, I want to continue using my overlays…
Of course, I could just rpm-ostree install … all of them, but there must be an easier way!

Cross-posted on Fedora Discussion

I tried rpm-ostree rollback, but that was not it. However, that command gave me a helpful hint. You can run:
rpm-ostree cleanup -p

This resets the pending deployments (-p) i.e. the ones you have not applied. The reset operation apparently also creates such a pending deployment, so if you then run the usual update…:
rpm-ostree upgrade

…you get back your layers and modifications, but have a new update e.g.
